# Print search term that does not exist in list comprehension of a list comprension

Tags: python, jython

I am a complete beginner with Python and am trying to do something in a single line of code.

```
resourceProperties = 'test test token test'
rpAttrs = [ ['ajgagag', 'knkagga'], ['token', 'knkagga'], ['ajgagag', 'knkagga'] ]

for value in rpAttrs if not list(re.finditer(value[0], resourceProperties)) : print value[0]
```

I get the following error and am not sure what exactly is wrong, because I have seen similar Python code where an if is immediately followed by a for on a list.

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

The error points to `if`.

My goal is to print every search term in `rpAttrs` that does not occur in `resourceProperties`.  I am curious to try and do this in only one line of code.  Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: none of the search terms in your example is a regular expression. Do you need regular expressions at all?

Comment: @1_CR No I suppose I do not.  I read somewhere on Stackoverflow that this was the way to search for a string occurrence within a string since Python does not have a `contains` method like Java or C#.  I guess what I am struggling with is syntactic confusions and how I can write code that not only works but is Pythonic and readable.

Comment: that makes it a little bit easier. See my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
list_comp = [value[0] for value in rpAttrs if not list(re.finditer(value[0], resourceProperties))]
>> ['ajgagag', 'ajgagag']
```

would be the correct way to do the comprehension

Answer (score 1):

You could try this, which is a bit more of a pythonic version of your loop and conditional:

```
import re
resourceProperties = 'test test token test'
rpAttrs = [['ajgagag', 'knkagga'], ['token', 'knkagga'], ['ajgagag', 'knkagga']]

print('\n'.join(value[0] for value in rpAttrs if not list(re.finditer(value[0], resourceProperties))))
```

This outputs:

```
ajgagag
ajgagag
```

Comment: Works fine for me in Python 2 and 3....I just edited my response with the full code that runs for me.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the colon python expects in the for syntax. You should break up your for/if blocks, it makes it easier to read and to catch bugs like this one. This should work:

```
for value in rpAttrs:
    if not list(re.finditer(value[0], resourceProperties)):
        print value[0]
```

As a side-note there are no list comprehensions here, just a list of lists. A list comprehension is a syntax for operating on a list (or list like thing) to create a new list, for example:

```
oddSquares = [number**2 for number in myListOfNumbers if (number % 2) == 1]
```

Comment: Ahh I see the colon is required unless it is within a comprehension, the result of which is a list!  Thanks that makes sense!

Answer (score 1):

Based on the OP's confirmation that only a "containment" check is needed

```
>>> print [value[0] for value in rpAttrs if not value[0] in resourceProperties]
['ajgagag', 'ajgagag']
```